# Root Domain Not Redirecting DNSimple

Tags: ssl, heroku, alias, cname, dnsimple

I currently have my application hosted on Heroku using an SSL. I purchased my SSL and setup the SSL endpoint and all works well using DNSimple.

The issue I am having is getting my root domain to redirect to my sub domain.

Currently our application is hosted only on the secured sub domain "example.website.com" and not on the root domain "website.com"

I have tried setting up an ALIAS, CNAME and URL redirect with DNSimple but every time I type in "website.com" I receive a Heroku Error: There is no app configured at that hostname.
Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.

If I type in www.website.com, it will successfully redirect to my secure sub domain url. Not sure why the root itself wont transfer

*SSL was NOT purchased as a wild card. It was granted a specific sub domain url

Comment: How about the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525344/redirecting-naked-domain-to-www-with-dnsimple

Answer (score 0):

In DNsimple you should use a URL type to redirect website.com to example.website.com. Here is a working setting  (this is the reverse of yours, ie www. to none www. address);

[image: Screenshot of DNSimple.]

It could be that you are not waiting long enough for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to having an issue with FireFox. I tested Safari and it redirected as well as Google Chrome. For some reason, FireFox will not work. However, if I visit www.website.com and then as long as I have not cleared my cache I can then put website.com and it will redirect. But that is a bad user experience for those that just want to type in website.com

Comment: Correction...I guess it only worked on my computer as I had others unsuccessfully test it

Comment: URL record types do not handle SSL redirects on DNSimple.  http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/url-redirect-ssl/