# Redirecting naked domain to www with DNSimple

Tags: heroku, dns, redirect, dnsimple

We're using DNS simple to point our domain to our SSL-enabled Heroku app. The behavior we're seeking is as follows:

http://ourdomain.com
https://ourdomain.com
http://www.ourdomain.com

Should all permanently redirect to:

https://www.ourdomain.com

We've already created a CNAME for www.ourdomain.com that points to our app's .herokussl.com domain, but we're not sure what to do with the naked domains. In GoDaddy, we used to do non-masked forwarding. DNSimple doesn't have forwarding, but does have special entries called ALIAS and URL, though we're not sure what to use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To configure a redirect you should use an URL record as described in our [redirect documentation](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/redirect).

However, it's not possible to [redirect an HTTPS URL](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/url-redirect-ssl) because of the priority between SSL negotiation and HTTP headers. In this case, because you also want `https://ourdomain.com` to redirect to `https://www.ourdomain.com`, then you need to [create an ALIAS for ourdomain.com to your Heroku SSL endpoint](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/domain-apex-heroku) and handle the redirect in your app.